# Matlab: Need to compact a vector of strings

Tags: string, matlab, vector, concatenation

I have 5 kilobytes of Hex data  per second coming in from a serial port. The data is 16 bits (2 bytes) per reading. There are 6 reading I need, followed by a stop/start bit. Raw data looks like this:

```
FF230008FF5800DD00F8000A41FF230008FF5800DE00FD000C41....
```

I'll break it up for better understanding:

```
FF23 0008 FF58 00DD 00F8 000A **41** FF23 0008 FF58 00DE 00FD 000C **41**....
```

Spaces are between the data I need. **'s indicate start/stop bits.

**Problem:**

I am having a heck of a time breaking the string into parts I can use and plot. I want to compress the string into a matrix of size [6 , length(data)]. The previous string would look like this in my head:

```
FF23 , 0008 , FF58 , 00DD , 00F8 , 000A 
FF23 , 0008 , FF58 , 00DE , 00FD , 000C
....
```

**My Failing Attempts**

```
for i = 1:(length(Vader)-4)
    Luke= Vader(i:i+3);
    i = i+4;
end
Luke
```

And it outputs:

```
00A4
```

Which is the correct answer for the data set I am looking at. Yes, I will have to deal with the stop/start bit, and that's not easy.

Still, I would like Luke to be more than just 1 set of 4 chars. I need is as at least a vector, not just a string. I tried this:

```
HanSolo = floor(length(Vader)/4);
for j = 1:HanSolo
    for i = 1:(length(Vader)-4)
        Luke(j) = Vader(i:i+3);
        i = i+4;
    end 
    j = j+1;
end
Luke
```

But I just get this error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> hex_conversion at 19
    Luke(j) = Vader(i:i+3);
```

Yes, MatLab, I know that there is a mismatch in dimensions. That is what I **want** to do.

**Question**

Essentially, after I reduce a string to a vector, character by character lets say, how do I make a new vector that is a concentration of Luke(j) = Vader(i:i+3)?

Thank you for any and all help, I appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I tried the below algorithm from user:Praetorian and it will not work. reshape() is not the right thing to use here, as the string I get in is of a variable number of the 26bits that i get in from the serial port. See sample here:

```
30008FF5A00DB00F9000A41
for clarity:
3 0008 FF5A 00DB 00F9 000A **41**
```

These pop up from time to time, as this is the real world and errors abound.

I am not asking for error checking though, I am still asking how to take a string, parse it into groups of 4 or so, and then put those blocks into a vector.

Again, thank you for any and all help

Comment: You must tell Luke the truth for your code to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for; no idea if it's the fastest solution ...

```m
% I duplicated the input you provided thrice
in = [...
'FF230008FF5800DD00F8000A41FF230008FF5800DE00FD000C41' ...
'FF230008FF5800DD00F8000A41FF230008FF5800DE00FD000C41' ...
'FF230008FF5800DD00F8000A41FF230008FF5800DE00FD000C41'];

% Reshape the vector of chars into 6 rows
in = reshape(in, size(in, 2)/6, 6)';

% Trim the trailing stop bits
in = in(:,1:end-2);

% Reshape it into a vector so we can get sscanf to read it
in = reshape(in', 1, prod(size(in)));

% Read 4 hex chars at a time and reshape the result into a matrix
out = reshape(sscanf(in, '%4x'), size(in, 2)/(4 * 6), 6)'
```

Result:

```
out =
   65315       8   65368     221     248      10
   65315       8   65368     222     253      12
   65315       8   65368     221     248      10
   65315       8   65368     222     253      12
   65315       8   65368     221     248      10
   65315       8   65368     222     253      12
```

Comment: Damn time limits on edits...

What I meant to say is that the above solution will not work for me, as the reshape() algorithm only takes in vectors. I first have to vectorize my string, which MatLab will not do. Also, the string is 200,000 chars long. 

Again, thank you

Comment: The 
    size(in, 2)/6
portion is not variable, and as the length of my string will be to a high extent, I can't use the reshape() algorithm. Thank you still.

Comment: Ok, I figured out a bit more:

Say I want to extend 'in' to 4 copies, 5 copies, etc, how would I go about doing that?